# Applying same function to each dataframe in list (in R) yields NA values or error

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

***Edit 2***:

I figured it out. Instead of using count which utilizes a table input, I just used nrow() and the results ended up producing exactly what I needed.

```
my.fun <- function(data,x,y,z,out) {data[out] <- data[[z]] / ((sum(data[[z]]^2)/nrow(data))^.5); data}
```

---

**Edit:**
Sorry, I completely forgot to post my.fun function. It is below:

```
my.fun <- function(data,x,y,out) {data[out] <- data[[y]] / rmse(data[[x]], data[[y]]); data}
```

I also tested it with the dataframe January and it worked without issue:

```
my.fun(monthSplit$January, x="swe_act_mm", y ="swe_mm", out = "d")
```

**Original Post:**
I've managed to get my timeseries split into month data frames, but am having trouble calculating the standardized residuals for each dataframe in one go. Each data frame spans from 2003 - 2008. The structure is as follows [taken from the November month]:

```
  $ November :'data.frame': 330 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..$ Date                                          : Date[1:330], format: "2005-11-01" "2005-11-02" "2005-11-03" "2005-11-04" ...
  ..$ swe_act_mm: num [1:330] 36 36 36 36 36 36 33 33 36 36 ...
  ..$ depth_cm          : num [1:330] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ site_id                                       : num [1:330] 946 946 946 946 946 946 946 946 946 946 ...
  ..$ POSIXct                                       : POSIXct[1:330], format: "2005-11-01" "2005-11-02" "2005-11-03" "2005-11-04" ...
  ..$ swe_mm                                        : num [1:330] 47.7 48.5 48.5 48.4 48.1 ...
  ..$ depth_m                                       : num [1:330] 0.27 0.265 0.256 0.248 0.241 ...
  ..$ SWE.Diff                                      : num [1:330] -11.7 -12.5 -12.5 -12.4 -12.1 ...
  ..$ Model.SD.Diff                                 : num [1:330] 0.27 0.265 0.256 0.248 0.241 ...
  ..$ SWE.RMSE                                      : num [1:330] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ year                                          : num [1:330] 2005 2005 2005 2005 2005 ...
```

There are 12 dataframes like this (one for each month).

I wanted to try and calculate the standardized residuals throughout the entire list of dataframes so I tried using lapply with a function:

```
lapply(monthSplit, my.fun, x="swe_act_mm", y="swe_mm", out="Standardized.SWE.RMSE")
```

The rmse function is from ModelMetrics, but yielded  " Error in rmse_(actual, predicted) :
Not compatible with requested type: [type=NULL; target=double]. "

So I then switched the equation to:

```
lapply(monthSplit, my.fun, x="swe_act_mm", y="swe_mm", z = "SWE.Diff", out="Standardized.SWE.RMSE")
```

```
my.fun <- function(data,x,y,z,out) {data[out] <- data[[y]] / ((sum(data[[z]]^2)/tally(data[[z]]))^.5); data}
```

However that yielded values of NA throughout the list for Standardized.swe.rmse. Is using lapply in this manner possible? Or do I need to individually calculate the standardized residuals for each data frame?

Comment: Your problem is in `my.fun` and without seeing that function's definition, it's next to impossible to figure out what's going on. Please update your question with that function's definition. You should also test your function with one of the dataframes first, before using `lapply`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my use of tally() I tried count() but I'm not sure how else to count the amount of rows.